# How to make an amount go up by certain amounts

Tags: python, multiplication

so I'm currently learning python and was wondering how to solve this code problem.
I'm trying to write a code which you input the amount of grams you would like, and then it outputs: how much it will cost and how much you will save.
The problem is I would like the grams price to drop when it reaches a certain amount, for example:
1 gram would be $20, 2.5 grams would be $50, 6 grams $100, 14 grams $180 and 28 grams 360. (all gram amounts between these would go up by the new $:gram ratio)

I tried to write a program using if statements and elif statements, it was all going pretty well until I added the third elif statement and then it would print out two elif sections or create errors.

```
equation = (grams * 20)
if equation < 50:
    print('That would be $', equation)

elif equation > 50:
    equation = (grams * 14.2857142857)
    equation_difference = (20 - 14.2857142857)
    saved = (equation_difference * grams)
    print('That would be $', round(equation))
    print('You saved $', round(saved))

elif equation >= 180:
    equation = (grams * 12.8571428571)
    equation_difference = (20 - 12.8571428571)
    saved = (equation_difference * grams)
    print('That would be $', round(equation))
    print('You saved $', round(saved))
```

Comment: in second elif add `elif equation >50 and equation <180` as third condition is not geting executing because, ur 2nd one is always true

Comment: Also, `equation==50` is not handled. One of the `equation<50` or `>50` should be  a `<=50` or `>=50` respectiveley

Answer (score 1):

Second elif needs to be

`elif equation < 120:`

Why not keep the grams without the *20?